# Make a flat file with different number of columns in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to make a flat file from 4 different sources, the problem I have is that each of the source has different number of columns, for example:

- Row P has these columns: R,N,I,P,U
- Row I has these columns: R,I,M,A,K
- Row M has these columns: R,I,M,M,R,MR
- Row R has these columns: R,I,M,M,C,R,A

All the 4 rows has different number of columns, how can I use SQL server integration services to have all these in one flat file, the merge component allows me to only merge 2 sources. Using SSIS 2008.

Comment: What are the four different sources?  All SQL server?  What do you mean by ROW P versus ROW I.  Did you mean table (source) P vs I?

Comment: the sources are SQL queries, all sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Since your 4 sources have different columns, you could try to use Derived Column transforms to create additional columns. This will make the number of columns equal for all 4 sources. Next, you could use a Union All transform to combine input from all sources, and then write to your flat file.

Comment: the additional columns will be separated by commas for a comma delimited file which we dont want

Comment: In that case, maybe you can use combinations of Execute SQL Tasks to retrieve data and Script Tasks to create/append to your target flat file.

Comment: don't understand, not concrete answer

Comment: Show concrete effort in question.